# Java 8 grammar has a part which causes syntax error when used in a real program

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, syntax, compiler-construction

So, I was going through the Java 8 grammar, and I found the following productions for certain nonterminals:

```
MultiplicativeExpression:
UnaryExpression 
MultiplicativeExpression * UnaryExpression 
MultiplicativeExpression / UnaryExpression 
MultiplicativeExpression % UnaryExpression

UnaryExpression:
UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus

UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus:
PostfixExpression 

PostfixExpression:
Primary 

Primary:
ArrayCreationExpression

ArrayCreationExpression:
new PrimitiveType DimExprs [Dims]
```

Note that I haven't listed out all the productions for the nonterminals that appear here. I have only listed those that I am now going to use to create a statement that gives syntax error in Java.

So, I use the production for *ArrayCreationExpression* to get `new int[3][][]`
Then this is reduced to *Primary*, which is then reduced to *PostfixExpression* and so on till the array creation is finally reduced to a *UnaryExpression*. This is used to get a *MultiplicativeExpression* of the following form:

`3 * new int[3][][]`

This is used to form a construction that reduces to nonterminal *Assignment* (whose productions I haven't listed here). That construction is:
```num = 3 * new int[3][][]``

Now, when compiling the following Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num3;
        num3 = 5 * new int[3][][];
    }
}
```

gives the following error:

```
prog.java:7: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
        num3 = 5 * new int[3][][];
                 ^
  first type:  int
```

How can code generated using Java grammar give syntax error when compiled?

Java 8 grammar: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html

The rules I used here are listed under the heading **Productions from §15 (Expressions)**

Comment: I don't think a `new int[3][][]` will get parsed into a `3 * new int[3][][]`.

Comment: @Trinopoty The `3 * ` will come later on. I said `new int[3][][] ` will get reduced to *UnaryExpression* which will be **used** as part of a bigger expression that will then get reduced to *MultiplicativExpression*.

Comment: "Bad operand types" is a type error, not a syntax error.

Comment: @sepp2k Oh, I see. So a type-checking phase would filter out such errors?

Comment: @ShashankKumar Yes, exactly.

Comment: Suppose you had `int a; int b; int[][][] c;` The expression statement `a = b * c;` has the same form as the one in the question. Clearly you cannot write a reasonable grammar that prohibits that.